# Show that the symmetric positive semidefinite cone $K = S_+^n$ is a proper cone.

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite

I am reading on Convex Optimization by Stephen Boyd.

I want to show that the symmetric positive semidefinite cone $K = S_+^n$, where $S_+^n$ is a set of symmetric $ n \times n$ matrices, is a proper cone

i am using the definition that a cone $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is called a proper cone if
K is convex, closed, pointed (contains no line) and nonempty.

Looking through, $S_+^n$ is indeed a convex cone, but I can't seem to prove to myself that it is also indeed a proper cone.

This is what I know so far:

To prove $S_+^n$ is convex, we can prove it by using:

$X \in S_+^n \iff Z^TXZ \geq 0, \forall Z$

$X \geq 0$, $Y \geq 0$

$Z^T(\theta_1 X + (\theta_2 Y)Z$

$ = \theta_1Z^TXZ + \theta_2Z^TYZ$

Hence, since $X$ and $Y$ are affine, they are convex and hence, $K$ is convex.

Comment: As you've written, you need to show that $K$ is closed, pointed, and has a non-empty interior (not just that the cone is non-empty)  Please show what you've attempted to do towards proving those things.

Comment: @BrianBorchers I have updated my question on how to prove its convexity. I can see the closedness topologically but I can't seem to do it algebraically. For pointed, I can see that it ultimately boils down to showing  (Sn+)∩(−Sn+) ={0}. But I can't seem to show it as well. Any guidance on these part?

Answer (score 1):

1. Pointed (contains no line.)

   We prove this by contradiction. If $K=S_+^n$ contains a line. Then there exists $A,B\in S_+^n$ and $A \ne B$ such that for any $\theta\in \mathbb{R}$, $\theta A+(1-\theta)B\in S_+^n$. Now if there exists $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$ s.t. $x^TAx\ne x^TBx$, without loss of generality. we assume $x^TAx > x^TBx$ then we can find $\theta$ s.t. $x^T(\theta A+(1-\theta)B)x<0$.

   \begin{align}
   x^T(\theta A+(1-\theta)B)x = \theta x^T Ax+(1-\theta) x^TBx< 0
   \end{align}
   if and only if
   $$\theta(x^TAx-x^TBx)<-x^TBx\Leftrightarrow \theta <-\frac{x^TBx}{x^TAx-x^TBx} $$
   which implies $\theta A+(1-\theta)B\not \in S_+^n$. So there doesn't exists $x$ s.t. $x^TAx=x^TBx$ which $A=B$ is the case. **Contradiction!**
2. $S_+^n$ is closed.

   [Here is a link from Math stackexchange, proving $S_+^n$ is closed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2904491/set-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrices-is-closed/2904495)

3. $S_+^n$ has non-empty interior.

   We can use example $I_{n\times n}\in S_+^n$ and $I_{n\times n}\succ 0$

Answer (score 0):

The following fact might help in proving that the cone is pointed: A symmetric matrix $A$ belongs to $S_{+}^{n}$ if and only if all the eigenvalues of $A$ is positive. Now write $A = U \Lambda U^{T}$, where $\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix containing all the eigenvalues of $A$. What can you say about the eigenvalues of $A$ if $A \in -S_{+}^{n}$, i.e., $-A\in S_{+}^{n}$?